# How to connect my react component to reflux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

I am kinda new to React and Reflux and modern JavaScript development. Trying to learn. So, I am making a component that is basically a sort of a chat window. A list with lines and an input box. When you type something into the input box and hit enter it adds the line to the list. I made it work with pure React using setState() and now I want to make it use a Reflux store. My component code goes like this

```
import React from 'react';
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import ConsoleActions from '../actions';
import ConsoleStore from '../stores';

export default React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(ConsoleStore, "lines")],
  render() {
    var lines = this.state.lines.map(function(line) {
      return(<li>{line}</li>)
    });
    return (
       <ul>{lines}</ul>
       <input onKeyUp={this.enter}/>
    )
  },
  enter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      ConsoleActions.addConsoleLines([e.target.value]);
      e.target.value = null
    }
  }
});
```

my actions are

```
import Reflux from 'reflux';

export default Reflux.createActions(["addConsoleLines","clearConsoleLog",]);
```

and my store is 
    import Reflux from 'reflux';

```
import Actions from './actions';

export default Reflux.createStore({
  lines: [],
  listenables: Actions,

  getInitialState: function() {
    return [];
  },

  addConsoleLines(lines) {
    lines.forEach(line => {
      this.lines.append(line);
    });
  },

  clearConsoleLog() {
    this.lines = []
  }
});
```

Not sure what I am missing, Reflux.connect() should connect my store to state, but I get "TypeError: this.state.lines is undefined" error.

Comment: From where `self` is coming into picture?

Comment: Oops... too much python. But I get the same error after replacing self with this in the store.

Comment: added init() to the store to set lines to [], still the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trigger change event when lines appended.

```
export default Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [Actions],
  lines:[],
  addConsoleLines(lines) {
    let self=this;
    lines.forEach(line => {
      self.lines.append(line);
    });
    self.trigger('change',self.lines);
  },

  clearConsoleLog() {
    this.lines = []
  }
});
```

And in your component listen for that change event

```
export default React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(ConsoleStore, "onChange")],
  onChange(event,_lines){
         this.setState({lines:_lines});
    }
  render() {
    var lines = this.state.lines.map(function(line) {
      return(<li>{line}</li>)
    });
    return (
       <ul>{lines}</ul>
       <input onKeyUp={this.enter}/>
    )
  },
  enter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      Actions.addConsoleLines([e.target.value]);
      e.target.value = null
    }
  }
});
```

**Edit1**: Yes you are correct. There is another simple way to this.
The `Reflux.connect()` mixin will check the store for a `getInitialState` method. If found it will set the components `getInitialState`. I think you forgot to return the initial state.

```
export default Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: Actions,

  getInitialState() {
        return [];
    },

  addConsoleLines(lines) {
   ...
  }
```

Comment: I thought Reflux.connect() was supposed to transparently bind store into component state. At least that is how it is written up in the docs.

"If all you want to do is update the state of your component to whatever the data store transmits, you can use Reflux.connect(listener,[stateKey]) as a mixin. If you supply a stateKey the state will be updated through this.setState({<stateKey>:data}), otherwise this.setState(data)."

Comment: @MadWombat Updated based on your commet. Still getting error?

Comment: I have updated the code, you are right, the docs actually say that connect() needs getInitialState() defined on the store. Now I get "TypeError: _this.lines is undefined". I have updated the code in my post.

Comment: on this `lines.forEach(line => {
      this.lines.append(line);
    });` you are getting error?

Comment: Also, I think I am not understanding the flux flow yet. If we trigger change event on the store and listen to it on the component, what do actions do?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the place where I get the error. A bit hard to be sure with webpack bundling things up.

Comment: Actions will call your methods defined on store and store will notify ui of changes so that it can update accordingly.

Comment: OK, I replaced it with lines.forEach(this.lines.push, this); and it seems to work. Now I get TypeError: self.trigger is not a function

Comment: Ah, the evils of cut and paste. this, not self.

Comment: Now I get "TypeError: this.state.lines.map is not a function". Argh!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103892/discussion-between-witvault-and-mad-wombat).

Comment: Not exactly a correct answer, but since it moved me in the right direction, I will mark it.